# Speeding Up VBA Code for If Then Statement with Formula

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, optimization

I currently have two if then VBA codes, that are running extremely slow for my large data set and am looking for ways to optimize and speed them up.

The first formula is looking in a range of cells in column J that have a value in column A, and if they are blank in J then entering in a formula that contains a user defined function.

The second code is looking to see if any of the values in column J end in a `,` and if they do then remove that comma. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub FillEmpty()
    Dim r As Range, LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For Each r In Range("J2:J" & LastRow)
        If r.Text = "" Then r.FormulaR1C1 = _
           "=IFERROR((IF(LEFT(RC[-9],6)=""master"", get_areas(RC[-7]), """")),"""")"
    Next r
End Sub

Sub NoComma()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("J:J")
        With c
            If Right(.Value, 1) = "," Then .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1)
        End With
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: seems like you should be able to combine these by putting the comma check if just after the previous if

Comment: The second If statement is easy, but can't you write the first one without FormulaR1C1? BTW I'm on it. Can I use calculating last row for the second If statement?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you! Can definitely use calculating last row for the second if statement. The formula for the first one would just be A2 and C2, respectively instead of the RC statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Speedup: Arrays

### 1. Code

It is unbelievable that you do not need formulaR1C1 to get a formula into the range when pasting from the array into range. But it's working on my computer. To conclude, the same principle from the second code is applied on the first: **Range into Array, Loop and Array into Range**. It doesn't get faster than this. The other idea for the first code was to create a range union and then paste the formula in one go.

```
Sub FillEmpty()

  Const cCol As Variant = "J"      ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cFirst As Long = 2         ' First Row

  Dim vntFE As Variant             ' Range Array
  Dim i As Long                    ' Range Array Rows Counter

  ' Paste range into array.
  vntFE = Cells(cFirst, cCol).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, cCol) _
      .End(xlUp).Row - cFirst + 1)

  ' Loop through array and perform calculation.
  For i = 1 To UBound(vntFE)
    If vntFE(i, 1) = "" Then vntFE(i, 1) = "=IFERROR((IF(LEFT(RC[-9],6)" _
        & "=""master"", get_areas(RC[-7]), """")),"""")"
  Next

  ' Paste array into range.
  Cells(cFirst, cCol).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, cCol) _
      .End(xlUp).Row - cFirst + 1) = vntFE

End Sub

Sub FillEmptyEasy()

  Const cCol As Variant = "J"      ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cFirst As Long = 2         ' First Row

  Dim rng As Range                 ' Range
  Dim vntFE As Variant             ' Range Array
  Dim LastRow As Long              ' Last Row
  Dim i As Long                    ' Range Array Rows Counter

  ' Calculate Last Row.
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row
  ' Calculate Range.
  Set rng = Cells(cFirst, cCol).Resize(LastRow - cFirst + 1)
  ' Paste range into array.
  vntFE = rng

  ' Loop through array and perform calculation.
  For i = 1 To UBound(vntFE)
    If vntFE(i, 1) = "" Then vntFE(i, 1) = "=IFERROR((IF(LEFT(RC[-9],6)" _
        & "=""master"", get_areas(RC[-7]), """")),"""")"
  Next

  ' Paste array into range.
  rng = vntFE

End Sub
```

### 2. Code

```
Sub NoComma()

  Const cCol As Variant = "J"      ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cFirst As Long = 2         ' First Row

  Dim vntNoC As Variant            ' Range Array
  Dim i As Long                    ' Range Array Rows Counter

  ' Paste range into array.
  vntNoC = Cells(cFirst, cCol).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, cCol) _
      .End(xlUp).Row - cFirst + 1)

  ' Loop through array and perform calculation.
  For i = 1 To UBound(vntNoC)
    If Right(vntNoC(i, 1), 1) = "," Then _
        vntNoC(i, 1) = Left(vntNoC(i, 1), Len(vntNoC(i, 1)) - 1)
  Next

  ' Paste array into range.
  Cells(cFirst, cCol).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, cCol) _
      .End(xlUp).Row - cFirst + 1) = vntNoC

End Sub


Sub NoCommaEasy()

  Const cCol As Variant = "J"      ' Column Letter/Number
  Const cFirst As Long = 2         ' First Row

  Dim rng As Range                 ' Range
  Dim vntNoC As Variant            ' Range Array
  Dim lastrow As Long              ' Last Row
  Dim i As Long                    ' Range Array Rows Counter

  ' Calculate Last Row.
  lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, cCol).End(xlUp).Row
  ' Calculate Range.
  Set rng = Cells(cFirst, cCol).Resize(lastrow - cFirst + 1)
  ' Paste range into array.
  vntNoC = rng

  ' Loop through array and perform calculation.
  For i = 1 To UBound(vntNoC)
    If Right(vntNoC(i, 1), 1) = "," Then _
        vntNoC(i, 1) = Left(vntNoC(i, 1), Len(vntNoC(i, 1)) - 1)
  Next

  ' Paste array into range.
  rng = vntNoC

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what you mean by simplification of the first code - can you please explain? The formula in the first code be simplified to just =get_areas(C2) if there was a way to set the range of cells to only be cells that are blank in column J and that start with "Master" in column A, and then put an IFERROR clause somewhere in the code to make those values blank.

Comment: @VictoriaG: I meant getting rid of formulaR1C1. But ok, I guess you cannot so I'll try like that. Will need at least an hour.

Comment: @VictoriaG: This might be it. Not sure what is happening in 'r.Text'. I hope it'll work since I've noticed you are suffering for days on this project.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I tried the code for Sub FillEmptyEasy and received an error about an object not being defined, but the other code worked well. And months, not days :)

Comment: @VictoriaG: Both easy versions' last line was wrong. Just remove 'Set'. Sorry. I've edited the answer.